# Safely remove a symlink or hardlink

Tags: symlink, rm, hard-link

Does using `rm` on a symlink or a hard-link remove the source in addition to the link? Is there a good way to delete a hard-link or a symlink without deleting the source?

And if there is a good way outside of `rm`, would it be a good idea to use this more frequently instead of `rm`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

rm always removes a link. If it's the last one, the space allocated to the  file is reclaimed. However, removing a symlink doesn't affect its target, so it seems like you've been misled.
If the file no longer has a name, how would you find it?

Comment: You're right, I must have done something wrong which may have mislead me. While it appeared using `rm` on a symlink deleted my file, I must have done something else to delete it and assumed it was `rm`-ing a symlink.

Comment: Maybe you did a tab-completion and ended up with a forward slash at the end of the symlink and that deleted the contents of the target as noted here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62647612/1745738